# Magento2 first module not working

Tags: magento2, module

After having made a working "Hello World" module, I tried to make my first magento 2 real module. The goal is to add a new product type. Using several tutorials, I did :

`Mine\Custproducttype\etc\module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mine_Custproducttype" schema_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`Mine\Custproducttype\etc\product_types.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="pcbproto" label="PCB Prototype" modelInstance="Mine\Custproducttype\Model\Product\Type\Pcbproto" indexPriority="10" sortOrder="25">
        <customAttributes>
            <attribute name="refundable" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="taxable" value="true"/>
        </customAttributes>
    </type>
    <composableTypes>
        <type name="pcbproto" />
    </composableTypes>
</config>
```

`Mine\Custproducttype\Model\Product\Type\Pcbproto.php`

```
<?php

namespace Mine\Custproducttype\Model\Product\Type;

class Pcbproto extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Product type code
     */
    const TYPE_CODE = 'pcbproto';

    /**
     * Delete data specific for Simple product type
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleteTypeSpecificData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
    }
}
```

`Mine\Custproducttype\registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mine_Custproducttype',
    __DIR__
);
```

When I add my module to the magento2 `app/code` directory all magento commands stop working (ex : `php bin/magento module:status`) and give an error :

> There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.

Removing the module and is starts working again.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Can you create composer.json file for your extension and then try.

Comment: what is the composer.json for?

Answer (score 0):

`schema_version` is not valid in a `module.xml` file anymore.

I don't remember in which version it happened but it has been replaced with `setup_version`

So you need to replace the following in your `module.xml` :

```
<module name="Mine_Custproducttype" schema_version="2.0.0">
```

With:

```
<module name="Mine_Custproducttype" setup_version="2.0.0">
```

Then you can run:

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Mine_Custproducttype
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: I was asked to recompile magento2. I then did it. All pages are blank now...I then disable the module. blank pages. Recompile magento again : the same. delete the module files, recompile, flush cash : still the same...

Comment: It was due to owner / rights problems... www-data / 777 works

Comment: @Alexglvr sweet yeah permissions are causing problems very often, glad you worked it out.